# sed : Need to remove all lines except first or last line that matches a string

Tags: regex, shell, sed, awk, sh

I have a text file with the following content

```
aa : 01
bb : 01
cc : 01
aa : 02
dd : 01
bb : 02
ee : 01
aa : 03
ff : 01
bb : 03
```

I need to keep first occurrence of line that has string "aa" in it and last occurrence of line that has string "bb" in it.

Please help.
Output should be

```
aa : 01
cc : 01
dd : 01
ee : 01
ff : 01
bb : 03
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this awk:

```
awk '!c && /^aa/{c=1;print;next} /^bb/{l=$0;next} !/^aa/ {print} END{print l}' file
aa : 01
cc : 01
dd : 01
ee : 01
ff : 01
bb : 03
```

Comment: What command to use if i need only to keep last occurrence of "bb" from the file ?

Comment: grep bb yourfile | tail -1

Comment: @Harsha: Use: `awk '!c && /^aa/{c=1;print;next} !d && /^bb/{d=1;print;next} !/^(aa|bb)/ {print}' file`